# R - sum from multiple dataframes

Tags: r, dplyr, aggregate

I am trying to see if there is any available function/package in R that can do the below in an easier manner. Please bear with me as I describe the problem.

I have a list of trades where I sum the Trade_value_local (Which is the total trade amount) by Funding_date and CCY_local as below.

```
library(dplyr)
    > Sum_Trade_Amt_by_Funding_Date_Ccy <- combined_list  %>% select(Funding_date, CCY_local, Trade_value_local) %>%
    +   group_by(Funding_date, CCY_local) %>%
    +   summarise(Total = sum(Trade_value_local))
    > 
    > Sum_Trade_Amt_by_Funding_Date_Ccy
    # A tibble: 9 x 3
    # Groups: Funding_date [?]
      Funding_date CCY_local    Total
      <date>       <chr>        <dbl>
    1 2018-01-15   HKD         767200
    2 2018-01-15   KRW       - 115870
    3 2018-01-15   TWD         923639
    4 2018-01-16   HKD       - 113985
    5 2018-01-17   INR        2307592
    6 2018-01-17   MYR        3089969

I have a cash forecast of balances by local currencies and dates:

> cash_forecast_long = read.csv("cash_forecast_long.csv", header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
> cash_forecast_long
   CCY_local       Day    Balance
1        AUD 1/10/2018   42984.41
2        HKD 1/10/2018  214412.85
3        INR 1/10/2018 1862292.95
4        KRW 1/10/2018      86.00
5        TWD 1/10/2018 2169925.00
6        USD 1/10/2018  873297.93
7        AUD 1/11/2018   32984.41
8        HKD 1/11/2018  214412.85
9        INR 1/11/2018 1862292.95
10       KRW 1/11/2018   20086.00
11       TWD 1/11/2018 5169925.00
12       USD 1/11/2018  573297.93
```

Is there any elegant / cleaner way with existing functions/packages of R) to build (extending) the cash forecast table that shows the cash balances for these additional dates?

To illustrate: 
For a currency and date where there are trades e.g.
Dataframe, cash_forecast is showing HKD balance of 214412.85 on 01/11/2018 (11-Jan-18). Dataframe, Sum_Trade_Amt_by_Funding_Date_Ccy is showing Total 767200 for HKD on 2018-01-15 (15-Jan-2018). The balance of HKD for 15-Jan-2018 would be the sum of Balance on 11-Jan-18 and Total on 15-Jan-18 and this row entry be added to cash_forecast.

For a currency and date where there are no trades e.g.
15-Jan-2018, where there is no AUD trades, cash_forecast AUD for 15-Jan-2018, would be just showing 32984.41 which is the same balance on 11-Jan-2018 and this row entry added to cash_forecast

Example output:

[image]

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding what you want. I think it would help if your sample data was shorter (and does `cash_forecast` matter at all? It seems like only `cash_forecast_long` is relevant), and also please show a complete sample output for the sample input, in the format you want it.

Comment: Hi Gregor, I removed the cash_forecast, shorten the sample data and shown a sample output data. Please let me know if this help. If not, I will try again. Thank you once again for responding.

Comment: It would be optimal to create the desired R output as formatted text in your Question instead of an Excel screenshot (because R console output is text).

Answer (score 0):

I am unclear what you really require here, as you can derive each day's trades directly from your cash forecast table without referring to any other table, which as far as I can tell means you don't need the Sum_Trade_Amt_by_Funding_Date_Ccy table at all. As the balance for each currency at the end of each day is just the opening balance plus any amount traded it is a straightforward task to manipulate the cash forecast table's balances to derive the trades, as long as the balances always change in line with whatever trades are made.

Using the example output version of your cash forecast table (name shortened to cf in the code below) the trades can be derived as a derived table cf1 as follows, ordered by currency type and day to show the way the trades are derived from the balances:

```
cf = arrange(cf, CCY_local, Day)
library(dplyr)    
cf1 = group_by(cf, CCY_local) %>%
  mutate(trade = Balance - lag(Balance)) %>%
  mutate(trade = ifelse(is.na(trade), 0, trade)) %>%
  select(CCY_local, Day, trade, Balance)

 > cf1
# A tibble: 18 x 4
# Groups:   CCY_local [6]
   CCY_local        Day    trade    Balance
       <chr>     <date>    <dbl>      <dbl>
 1       AUD 2018-01-10        0   42984.41
 2       AUD 2018-01-11   -10000   32984.41
 3       AUD 2018-01-15        0   32984.41
 4       HKD 2018-01-10        0  214412.85
 5       HKD 2018-01-11        0  214412.85
 6       HKD 2018-01-15   767200  981612.85
 7       INR 2018-01-10        0 1862292.95
 8       INR 2018-01-11        0 1862292.95
 9       INR 2018-01-15        0 1862292.95
10       KRW 2018-01-10        0      86.00
11       KRW 2018-01-11    20000   20086.00
12       KRW 2018-01-15  -115870  -95784.00
13       TWD 2018-01-10        0 2169925.00
14       TWD 2018-01-11  3000000 5169925.00
15       TWD 2018-01-15 -2076361 3093564.00
16       USD 2018-01-10        0  873297.93
17       USD 2018-01-11  -300000  573297.93
18       USD 2018-01-15        0  573297.93
```

To show that this does indeed derive your sum_trade_amt table we can filter the results to show only the trades, and arrange by date:

```
cf2 = filter(cf1, trade != 0) %>%
  select(Day, CCY_local, trade) %>%
  arrange(Day, CCY_local)

> cf2
# A tibble: 7 x 3
# Groups:   CCY_local [5]
         Day CCY_local    trade
      <date>     <chr>    <dbl>
1 2018-01-11       AUD   -10000
2 2018-01-11       KRW    20000
3 2018-01-11       TWD  3000000
4 2018-01-11       USD  -300000
5 2018-01-15       HKD   767200
6 2018-01-15       KRW  -115870
7 2018-01-15       TWD -2076361
```

In the limited data provided in the question the amounts apparently traded do not in all cases match what you showed in the Excel screenshots. For instance, you show 15-01-2018 TWD traded 923639, but that does not match your balances of 5169925 on 11/1/2018 going to 3093564 on 15/1/2018, a negative amount of -2076361 as shown in the cf2 table above.

**Data Setup**

```
cf = read.table(text = "CCY_local Day Balance
AUD 1/10/2018 42984.41
HKD 1/10/2018 214412.85
INR 1/10/2018 1862292.95
KRW 1/10/2018 86.00
TWD 1/10/2018 2169925.00
USD 1/10/2018 873297.93
AUD 1/11/2018 32984.41
HKD 1/11/2018 214412.85
INR 1/11/2018 1862292.95
KRW 1/11/2018 20086.00
TWD 1/11/2018 5169925.00
USD 1/11/2018 573297.93
AUD 1/15/2018 32984.41
HKD 1/15/2018 981612.85
INR 1/15/2018 1862292.95
KRW 1/15/2018 -95784.00
TWD 1/15/2018 3093564.00
USD 1/15/2018 573297.93", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

cf$Day = as.Date(cf$Day, "%m/%d/%Y")
```